# SQL GROUP BY and ORDER BY not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have query:

```
SELECT p.* FROM `our_projects` AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `news_categories` nc ON p.sort = nc.categories_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `news` n ON nc.news_id = n.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY n.date_show DESC
```

`our_projects` table: have 9 records
`news_categories` table: have multiple records, this is categories of news.
`news`: this is table of news.

I want order by date_show column of news, but group by not working correctly. I get not correctly order, not by date_show of news.

I get in table our_project ORDER BY ID DESC WHY??:

1) 108 - last news 25 feb 
2) 111 - last news 24 feb 
3) 114 - last news 24 feb 
4) 117 - last news 9 feb 
5) 120 - last news 23 feb 
6) 123 - last news 24 feb 
7) 126 - last news 23 feb 
8) 129 - last news 9 feb 
9) 132 - last news 22 feb

Why??

Comment: What is the reason you thought to use `GROUP BY` without any aggregates (e.g. min/max/avg) ?

Comment: Because if I don't use GROUP BY, then I don't get distinct records of table our_projects. I get duplicates

Comment: Are you looking for the _latest_ news story per category?

Comment: Why not use `distinct` in first place?

Comment: Yes, I look latest news per category.

Comment: I try use DISTINCT, but get same results of GROUP BY.

Comment: which column u want distinct

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix for what you want would be to join to a subquery which identifies the latest news story for each new category.  In the query below, the subquery aliased as `t` does precisely this.  It will filter off all news stories except for the most recent one per category.

```
SELECT p.*, nc.*, n.*
FROM our_projects p 
LEFT JOIN news_categories nc
    ON p.sort = nc.categories_id 
LEFT JOIN news n
    ON nc.news_id = n.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.categories_id, MAX(t2.date_show) AS max_date_show
    FROM news_categories t1
    INNER JOIN news t2
        ON t1.news_id = t2.id
    GROUP BY t1.categories_id
) t
    ON nc.categories_id = t.categories_id AND
       n.date_show      = t.max_date_show
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    n.date_show;
```

Comment: No this is not working. I get bad order records of table our_projects. I need order by n.date_show DESC.

Comment: Then edit your question and show us data which explains the problem.  Based on your comment, you said you want the latest news per category, and my query does this.

Comment: My query should already be doing this.  One last time, please edit your question and show us data.

Comment: Your update does little to explain the problem or why my query is not correct.  What about the output from my query seems wrong to you?

Comment: I get order by id our_projects DESC. But not order by n.date_show DESC. This is a problem on your query.

Comment: @Tatata Then use `ORDER BY n.date_show` at the end of my query.  Is this so hard for you to figure out?

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT ME?

Comment: _Excuse me_?  Your question, 3 hours later, is still incomplete, and does not even show us the expected output.

Comment: I added table preview